# Swift 'if let ... as?' safe unwrap with NSMutableArray

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray, option-type

I'm learning how to safely unwrap optionals in Swift, for some reason however filteredList[0] must be returning nil here, as none of the code inside the if let statement is executing. However, printing the filteredList ensures that there is something inside that NSMutableArray! It seems pretty simple, but why is this returning nil? and/or the code inside the if let statement not executing?

```
func filterOutNoItemsInCommon(randomItem: (NSArray) -> NSDictionary, listOfItems: NSArray) -> (NSArray, NSArray, Set<String>) {

var filteredList = NSMutableArray()
var filteredListCounter = 0
var setOfAtt: Set = Set<String>()
var selectedItem = NSArray()
var rank: Int = 0

if let itemArray: NSArray = randomItem(listOfItems)["attributes"] as? NSArray {
    selectedItem = itemArray
    for item in itemArray {
        setOfAtt.insert(item as! String)
    }
}

for number: Int in 0..<listOfItems.count {

    rank = 0

    if let listOfItems = (listOfItems[number]["attributes"] as? NSArray) {
    if let arrayOfItems = listOfItems as? Array<String> {

        if !setOfAtt.isDisjointWith(arrayOfItems) {

            filteredList.addObject(listOfItems[number])

            for ln in arrayOfItems {
                if setOfAtt.contains(ln) {
                    rank++
                }
            }

            var dictForRank: NSMutableDictionary = ["rank": rank]
            println(dictForRank)
            println("TEST\(filteredList[0])")
            // this is where the code doesn't execute
            if let thisIsAnArray = filteredList[0] as? NSMutableArray {
                println("TEST123")
                println(thisIsAnArray)
                filteredList[filteredListCounter].addObject(dictForRank)
            }

            filteredListCounter++
        }
    }
    }

}

return (filteredList, selectedItem, setOfAtt)
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what's your `filteredList` looks like. If `Test` is, then it's a `Dictionary` type not `Array` type. Since you are using Swift, you better use `Array` instead of `NSMutableArray` unless you have reason to do so.

Comment: In other words we need the declaration of `filteredList`, but it's probably not a Swift-style array of Objective-C `NSMutableArray`s, which would be pretty weird. It's not `nil`, sure, but it's some other type.

Comment: @BaseZen it's a JSON object that I assigned to an instance of NSMutableArray not sure how to show that

Comment: Show us the line of code where it's declared. It's looking more like an `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: @LucasHuang You're not accounting for the fact that the iOS NSJSONSerialization library uses Objective-C style structures.

Comment: The edit is making things worse, I think, because nowhere does it show filteredList being *added* to from its empty state, and the output is now mixed in with the code

Comment: @BaseZen yea I'm sorry. I thought I was going to make it easier by editing out irrelevant code but it just made things worse. There's a comment where the if let statement won't execute

Comment: @BaseZen You are right, but the OP dose not say something about that. Thanks for that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object is an `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary`, not an `NSMutableArray`, so the safe downcast is failing.

Your reasoning that it is `nil` is incorrect; either `nil` *or* an incompatible type will cause a safe unwrap/downcast to fail.

Comment: I know you've accepted this, but I'm not even sure of that. You're doing a very confusing `let` where a contained object is taking over the name of the container: `if let listOfItems = (listOfItems[number]["attributes"] as? NSArray)` Please use a different identifier for the `let`!

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. It makes it rather confusing doesn't it. The issue was that filteredList itself is an NSMutableArray, but filteredList[0] is an NSMutableDictionary. It's a dictionary inside the array.